# send("!N") is not working

Tags: autoit

I want to automate an installer. I started the installer with `shellexecute`. The problem is that the send command is not working. The installer is actualy a self-extracting archive that extracts three files:

1. setup.exe
2. A 64-bit [MSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Installer)
3. A 32-bit MSI

After the extraction, `setup.exe` is started, which detects whether the OS is 32- or 64-bit and then launches the msi acording to the detected OS.
Now I need to send a key, pressing the next button on the MSI, but it is not working.
If I run the MSI file straight, it works, but when I run this way, the installer fails.

Basically, I need to run an EXE file and send keys to an MSI file. How can this be done?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: i have no code i truyed all the samples i found and none worked

Comment: With out code or the installer there isn't much we can do.

Comment: You are having a window focus problem. You need to ensure the correct expected window is in focus by using `WinActivate("your window title")` before attempting to send keys to it. -- See my answer below for a sample script that uses this.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are sending keys to cyberspace! ;-P

No, but really, it sounds like a window focus issue where you are sending keys but they are not landing on the window you are expecting. You need to use `WinActivate("you_window_title")` to grab onto the correct window.

Run your installer by hand and notate all of the window titles that pop up over the installation. Then in your script you can make sure the window you are expecting to be in focus, is in focus.

Use something along the lines of:

```
Run(your_installer.exe)                       ; execute your installer
Sleep(2500)                                   ; sleep for 2.5 seconds waiting for the exe to do it's thing and eventually open the msi

;;;;~~ This is how you would now grab onto the new msi installer's window ~~;;;; 
WinActivate("Your Installer Window's Title")  ; make sure the installer window is in focus
;;;;~~                                                                    ~~;;;;

Send("{TAB}")                                 ; tab around the window that's in focus
Send("{ENTER}")                               ; press <ENTER> on the "NEXT" button
Sleep(100);                                   ; sleep for 100ms while the next page loads
Send("{TAB}")                                 ; tab again to select a checkbox for the "I agree" on the EULA
Send("{SPACE}")                               ; space will toggle the checkbox to checked (I agree)
Send("+{TAB}")                                ; tab back to the NEXT button
Send("+{TAB}")                                ; still tabbing to the next button
Send("{ENTER}")                               ; now hit enter on the next button

; etc... ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the window is focused and the button "Next" is focused as well?
Just run the executable using ShellExecute and try to press the enter key to see if the button is focused.

Comment: ShellExecute("a.exe")
Send ("!n") dosen't work when running the installer. running on the msi and skiping the autoextract and os detection oworks. pressing on the enter key on the keyboard causes the installet to go to next step

Comment: Could you upload the installer, so I can check it on my computer? Maybe I can help you this way